# Control flow understanding

Tags: c, control-flow

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding the following program flow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{
 FILE *fp;
 int index = 0;
 char word[45];
 int words = 0;

 fp = fopen("names.txt","r");
 if(fp == NULL) 
 {
   perror("Error in opening file");
   return(-1);
 }


 for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
 {
     // allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
     if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
     {
         // append character to word
         word[index] = c;
         index++;

         // ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
         if (index > 45)
         {
             // consume remainder of alphabetical string
             while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

             // prepare for new word
             index = 0;
         }
     }

     // ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
     else if (isdigit(c))
     {
         // consume remainder of alphanumeric string
         while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

         // prepare for new word
         index = 0;
     }

     // we must have found a whole word
      else if (index > 0)
     {
         // terminate current word
         word[index] = '\0';

         // update counter
         words++;

         //prepare for next word
         printf("%s\n", word);
         index = 0;
     }
     //printf("%s\n", word);
 }

 printf("%s\n", word);

 fclose(fp);
 return(0);
}
```

As you can see, it's just a plain program that stores characters from words into an array, back-to-back, from a file called 'names.txt'.

My problem resides in the `else if(index > 0)` condition.
I've run a debugger and, obviously, the program works correctly.

Here's my question:

On the first for-loop iteration, `index` becomes 1. Otherwise, we wouldn't be able to store a whole word in an array.

If so, how is it possible that, when the program flow reaches the `else if (index > 0)` condition, it doesn't set `word[1]` to 0? (Or the subsequent values of `index`).

It just finishes the whole word and, once it has reached the end of the word, then it proceeds to give `word[index]` the value of 0 and proceed to the next word.

I've tried reading the documentation, running half of the program and asking with echo, and running a debugger. As it should be, everything runs perfectly, there's no problem with the code (as far as I know).  I'm the problem. I just can't get how it works.

PS: sorry if this might be so trivial for some of you, I'm really starting to learn programming and I find sometimes really hard to understand apparently so simple concepts.

Thank you very much for you time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as something is executed in the `if...else` block, it moves out of the block. So if it satisfies the first `if` condition, the `else if` condition is not even checked. So if index > 0 AND c=\ or c is an alphabet, it runs the if statement, and if even one of these conditions does not hold true, it will move to the else if portions of the block.

Comment: Oh, I see! So basically that's the difference between an `else if` and an `if` when it comes to control-flow, right? 

Thank you very much @lordingtar ! I can see it perfectly right now! 

Marking this answer and correct and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Note the `else` in the beginning of the `else if (index > 0)` condition.

This means that it will only execute if none of the previous `if()` and `else if()` executed.

The previous `if()` and `else if()` statements do keep executing if the character is alphanumeric, or a non-leading slash, so the last `else if()` only executes once a non-alphanumeric, or leading slash is encountered.

Comment: I see now! Thank you very much @Mike Nakis for your answer!